# Undefined array key "id". Laravel 8 send:notification command

Tags: javascript, android, mysql, laravel, oracle-sqldeveloper

I am trying to send a notification to the enrolled users in an event a day before the event's start date. I have a user table events table that contains the start date of each event. Also, I have an enrollment table that includes the user_id and event_id as foreign keys and the start date of these events. However, while I was trying to code the logic of this function and executing it, I got this error.

```
class SendNotification extends Command
```

[image]

Comment: Welcome to SO ... please edit your question and add the code in a code block, not as an image

Answer (score -1):

You are using collection when you call Model::all() and you are trying to use it like an array but it is a collection.

```
$enrolls = Enroll::all()->keyBy('user_id')->all();
```

then run your if check like

```
if (isset($enrolls[$user->id]))
```

I can not copy your code because you shared screenshot not a code. So be aware of that for your next question.